# How to call a method from parent classes that are instances of the same template [boost::enable_shared_from_this]

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code.

```
class A: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
  public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    boost::shared_ptr<A> returnMe() {
      return shared_from_this();
    }
};

class B: public A, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
    boost::shared_ptr<B> returnMe() {
      return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

gcc complains that the shared_from_this is ambiguous. 
* In this case, is it safe to use `boost::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this()` or
`this->boost::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this()`
in the returnMe of B?
* Both A and B inherited from enable_shared_from_this with different parameters. Does it seem correct? Or I need to do something else?
If B does not inherit enable_shared_from_this, using `shared_from_this()` in B returns `shared_ptr<A>`. If so, is it safe to `static_pointer_cast` it to be `shared_ptr<B>`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing to something like `return enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this();` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two bases that provide `shared_from_this`, but the types of the bases is distinct and thus you can use that to disambiguate:

```
shared_ptr<B> returnMe() {
   return static_cast<boost::enable_shared_from_this<B>*>(this)->shared_from_this();
}
```

That being said, the design might be a bit more complicated than what you want, in particular `returnMe` is not a virtual function (and cannot be, different non-covariant return type), which means that if you pass `B` to a function that takes a reference or pointer to `A` and they call `shared_from_this()` it will get the *wrong* version of the object.

While `shared_ptr` supports aliasing, and there is no technical reason, the interfaces don't support the configuration of `enable_shared_from_this<A>` to yield a `shared_ptr<A>` that can share ownership with the `shared_ptr<B>` that is managing the whole object.

If you can make the base pure virtual (remove the `enable_shared_from_this` and the `returnMe` functions) you will have a cleaner interface, less confusing as of what might work and how.

Comment: With your fix, does boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(boost::static_pointer_cast<A>(b)->returnMe()) equal to b->returnMe()? b is B's object. Do they actually return share_ptrs to the same obj and share the same reference counter?